# Como fazer botão Inclinado?

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou usando img mas não é uma boa prática, então gostaria de usar um button com algum atributo css. É possivel?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Uma alternativa seria usar os elementos pseudos `:before` e `:after` combinado com `border` e `position` você pode adicionar estas duas "cantos" inclinadas, ou seja o efeito é "simulado", exemplo:

```css
.exemplo {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;/*faz os elementos pseudos acompanharem o elemento com a classe*/
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #CC0000;
  line-height: 20px; /*Centraliza o texto*/
  height: 20px;
  padding:0 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.exemplo:before, .exemplo:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.exemplo:before {
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #CC0000;
  left: -5px;
}

.exemplo:after {
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #CC0000;
  right: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="exemplo">test</div> <div class="exemplo">test</div>
```

Para os cantos conforme a altura, altere o `border-width` de 20px para a altura desejada em:

```
.exemplo:before {
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
```

e

```
.exemplo:after {
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
```

Para ajustas a inclinação você deve alterar o `border-right` e o `left` de `.exemplo:before` e alterar
`border-left` e o `right` de `.exemplo:after`

Answer (score 13):

Podes usar [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) com `skew` assim:

```
#inclinada {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
            transform: skew(-20deg);
    background: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5b5eboeg/

No meu exemplo usei `margin` e `padding`, e outras propriedades, mas isso é  opcional. O importante é o `transform: skew(-20deg);` e as suas variantes para browsers diferentes.

Muda os graus de inclinamento para adaptar ao que precisas.

Para o texto não ficar também inclinado podes fazer assim (https://jsfiddle.net/5b5eboeg/1/) [como o @bfavaretto referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto) ou assim (https://jsfiddle.net/5b5eboeg/2/) [como o @mgibsonbr referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/215/mgibsonbr)

Comment: Eu fiquei com a impressão de que o texto na pergunta não está inclinado, enquanto o do seu exemplo está. Uma solução (gambiarra?) para isso seria colocar mais uma tag dentro, e aplicar um skew inverso nela.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ou talvez duas divs com posicionamento absoluto, uma (não transformada) em cima da outra (transformada).

Comment: Só boas ideias!... vou juntar

Comment: exatamente o que ia perguntar rs, testei font-style: normal;

Comment: Como a sugestão do bfavaretto funcionou bem, ela é preferível em relação à minha - mais organizado hierarquicamente, mais simples de se aplicar estilos/ações.