# Botão na diagonal só o lado esquerdo

Tags: html, css, css3

tenho que fazer um botão dessa forma no CSS:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que consigo fazer isso recortando a imagem e colocando o `input` como `image` mas queria fazer isso no `CSS`. Achei uma forma que QUASE me ajudaria que seria:

```
.botao{
    transform: skew(10deg);
}
```

Mas ele gira o botão e deixa com as 2 pontas cortadas (como a imagem abaixo, só que do lado direito a mesma coisa). Precisa deixar conforme a imagem acima.

Comment: já tentei uma vez com o trapézio, mas ele trabalha com bordas ai não consegui escrever dentro...

Comment: da uma olhada nesse link http://stackoverflow.com/a/27720597/5650313

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a combinação de `position: relative` com `position: absolute` junto a um pseudo elemento como `:before` ou `:after`, semelhante a esta que eu respondi [**Como fazer botão Inclinado?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56827/3635)

Neste exemplo eu removi o pseudo elemento `:after` (só necessitaremos de um, no caso o `:before`) também necessitará trocar o `border-top` por `border-bottom` se quiser que inclinação termine na parte superior do botão.

Se quiser a inclinação do lado *esquerdo* (aqui você deve ajustar o `border-bottom` conforme o `height`, ou seja ambos devem ter o mesmo tamanho):

```css
.botao {
  border: none; /*remove borda do elemento button*/
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;/*faz os elementos pseudos acompanharem o elemento com a classe*/
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #CC0000;
  line-height: 20px; /*Centraliza o texto*/
  height: 20px;
  padding:0 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.botao:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid #CC0000;
  left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<button class="botao">tag BUTTON</button>
<div class="botao">tag DIV</div>
```

Se quiser a inclinação do lado *direito*, troque `right:` por `left:` e `border-right` por `border-left` dentro do pseudo elemento (aqui você deve ajustar o `border-top` conforme o `height`, ou seja ambos devem ter o mesmo tamanho):

```css
.botao {
  border: none; /*remove borda do elemento button*/
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;/*faz os elementos pseudos acompanharem o elemento com a classe*/
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #CC0000;
  line-height: 20px; /*Centraliza o texto*/
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  padding:0 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.botao:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #CC0000;
  right: -15px;
}
```

```html
<button class="botao">tag BUTTON</button>
<div class="botao">tag DIV</div>
```

Aplicando o efeito bem próximo ao que espera:

```css
.botao {
  border: none; /*remove borda do elemento button*/
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;/*faz os elementos pseudos acompanharem o elemento com a classe*/
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #DC005E;
  line-height: 65px; /*Centraliza o texto*/
  text-align: center;
  height: 65px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 260px;
}

.botao:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 65px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid #DC005E;
  left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="botao">tag BUTTON</button>
<div class="botao">tag DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Segue abaixo uma opção de como fazer:

```css
.forma {
  border-top: 60px solid #DB005C;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: transparent;
  border-bottom: transparent;
  width: 250px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  
}

.textoForma {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 30px;
  font-size: 43px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

button:focus {
  outline:0;
}
```

```html
<button class="forma">
  <p class="textoForma">ENVIAR</p>
</button>
```

Comment: `+1` Ficou bem mais legal que meu pog lá hahaha só add um cursor pointer e um hover e fica um button de verdade. https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/q41p91ef/

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, editei a resposta e adicionei o `cursor:pointer`, agora fico top, vlw !

Comment: Perceba também que a área da div é maior que a área desenhada, é possível acessar o cursor de fora do button.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, arrumei .. vlw

Answer (score 2):

Utilizei transform-origin, deu pra chegar bem próximo:

**Exemplo:**

```css
button {
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #DC005E;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(-30deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(-30deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(-30deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  margin: 10px 90px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #FDFEFE;
}
```

```html
<button>Enviar</button>
```